# "Outside there is a money receiver which only accepts coins" - or "that only accepts coins"? Which relative pronoun is better?

Tags: pronouns, relative-clauses, restrictive-clauses

I'm preparing for academic IELTS by writing some essays and then correcting those using a grammar correction app.

In the following sentence,

> Outside there is a money receiver which only accepts coins

The app suggests using "that" instead of "which". But is "which" also acceptable, or is it a critical mistake?

Comment: What is a "money receiver"?

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff I suspect some kind of vending machine. E.g. at a train station, the machine you use to buy tickets.

Comment: Be aware that "money receiver" sounds ridiculous in English.  If it means anything, it would mean a person (perhaps at a bank, storehouse, or mint) who is in charge of arriving trucks.

Comment: Is the money-receiver a machine or a human? In the latter case, I'd use "who."

Comment: *"[if writers would agree to regard that as the defining relative pronoun, & which as the non-defining, there would be much gain both in lucidity & in ease. Some there are who follow this principle now; but it would be idle to pretend that it is the practice either of most or of the best writers.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/when-to-use-that-and-which)"* — this is one of those "rules" in English that's worth knowing of, but only if you want to appease or rebutt people (and spellcheckers) who think you're wrong. Either is actually fine.

Comment: @Fattie Or maybe a specific component of an ATM that accepts deposits.

Comment: @nick012000 - indeed.  (By a bizarre and amazing coincidence, I once owned some vending machines, so I probably said just that once or twice!)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In prescriptive English, "which" should only introduce non-restrictive relative clauses, those that are offset by a comma and aren't intrinsic to the subject, but give more information about it. Your example uses a restrictive clause, so "that" is the better option. (There are plenty of resources that go into detail on relative clauses, should you need it.)

This rule is purely prescriptivist, and native English speakers ignore it all the time. It is usually observed in formal writing though, so you're definitely best off learning it and using it "properly" in your exam.

Comment: It definitely depends on the context; no English speaker here would notice. If anything, "that" would feel slightly wrong compared to "which".

Comment: I've never heard of the rule that "which" should only be used with non-restrictive clauses before. Can you please provide a source for that?

Comment: Well done for providing the formal, grammatical reason; _which_ and _that_ are not interchangeable. 1) _The Eiffel Tower is in Paris, which is the capital of France_ (the identification of France's capital is supplementary information that can be omitted). 2) _Do not miss the meeting that is on Tuesday_ (the day of the important meeting is vital to the meaning of the sentence).

Comment: @TannerSwett I am only familiar with the rule from Microsoft Word, which has been insisting upon it for well over a decade.  I've never heard of it anywhere else until now, but I'm quite sure it doesn't match a large amount of general usage.

Answer (score 16):

In this context, I think "that" and "which" are completely interchangeable and either one is completely acceptable.

[the-baby-is-you's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/277078/2020) states that "In prescriptive English, 'which' should only introduce non-restrictive relative clauses." I never heard of such a prescription before today, and I think that using "which" for restrictive relative clauses (which is what the phrase "money receiver which only accepts coins" does) is very common in skilled, careful writing.

In order to try to verify this, I decided to look through the opinions of the Supreme Court of the United States in *Obergefell v. Hodges* (2015). I found 12 usages of "which" for a restrictive relative clause which could have been written using "that" instead. Out of these, most of them were original text, but there were also multiple usages in quotes from the 18th century, and multiple from the 19th century as well.

I admit that some sources say that "which" shouldn't be used restrictively, such as [this Grammarly page](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/which-vs-that/) that [Barmar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/6111/barmar) posted a link to in a comment on this answer. On the other hand, [this page at merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/when-to-use-that-and-which), linked to by [zhantongz](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/73846/zhantongz), points out that "which" has been used restrictively since the "youth" of the English language, and that any rules against such usage were made artificially and never really caught on.

Personally, I think that the long history of use of restrictive "which" by skilled, careful writers is proof that it's totally fine. Other people disagree.

Comment: It is a pretty widely known prescription. I deliberately follow it in formal (legal) writing, but it is not obeyed by most native speakers as you say.

Comment: This "rule" is fairly widespread (e.g. Lexico/Oxford and Purdue OWL). Merriam-Webster has a brief historical outlook on this widely disregarded non-rule. https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/when-to-use-that-and-which

Comment: If you ever grammar-check an MS Word document, you'll get flagged on this all the time. It's a well-known issue, on par with a split-infinitive, and ignored almost as much.

Comment: @OscarBravo: To my mind, "it's on par with a split infinitive" = "it's a fake rule you should completely ignore."

Comment: @Kevin To constantly split inifinitives, that is something I would never do, means literally throwing the baby out with the bathwater.

Comment: @OscarBravo: That's bad because *it's clunky and hard to read* (e.g. because you're not writing in SVO order), not because it splits infinitives.

Comment: Grammar rules are all about describing how native speakers speak and write.  They're not about allowing Microsoft to legislate how people speak, via their proprietary grammar checkers.

Comment: @Kevin you should know made-up rules though, because examiners often like to grade people on made-up rules anyway...

Comment: @Kevin Up with irony, I would not put.

Comment: @user253751: I graduated years ago. I don't care what the examiners think, because they are wrong.

Comment: @Kevin The person asking the question cares, because they are taking an exam.

Answer (score 14):

One issue is this:

It is ***extremely unlikely that an English speaker, in spoken English, would say***

> Outside there is a vending machine ...

They would say

> There's a vending machine outside ...

***given that***, it's true that

> There's a vending machine outside that only takes coins.

would be used far more than

> There's a vending machine outside which only takes coins.

- which sounds almost archaic or pseudo-formal.

***However***

The formulation is extremely unrealistic. Any English speaker would say

> There's a vending machine outside, but it only takes coins.

You would only use the very unrealistic formulation from the question, in this extremely unusual situation:

> "Hmm, most vending machine take both credit cards and coins. I wonder if there exist any vending machines that only take coins?"  "You won't believe it! There's a vending machine right outside that only takes coins!"

Other than in that bizarre example, there's no reason an English speaker would say

> There's a vending machine outside that only takes coins.

they would say

> There's a vending machine outside, but it only takes coins.

Comment: This is arguably not so much about ‘what a native English speaker would say’, but ‘what the most likely actual meaning to come up in conversation would be’. The choice of using a restrictive clause with ‘that’ versus just having a completely separate clause introduced with ‘but’ has nothing to do with style here, it actually changes the contextual meaning of the sentence. That said, I agree that the ‘Outside there is’ formulation sounds a bit odd to a native speaker.

Comment: hi @AustinHemmelgarn  indeed that's the whole point of my post.  Regarding the whacky question from the test in the OP.  The only possible realistic meaning is the one I give in my "extremely unusual situation".

Comment: As a native English speaker, I would say "There's a vending machine outside which only takes coins." a lot more than "There's a vending machine outside that only takes coins".

Comment: I agree with the general sentiment, if not the precise judgments (and another more plausible context would be giving directions). But good on you for identifying that the choice of 'which' vs 'that' is not going to be the non-native 'tell' in this sentence.

Comment: As a native English speaker, I don't believe the respondent here speaks for all of us.

Comment: @Puppy You'd say that because you're relying on your ear, rather than obeying a defined rule of grammar. Use _comma-which_ when the clause is optional and can be removed. Use _that_ when the clause adds essential meaning.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that "_only takes coins_" is conversational (and ambiguous, as it may mean it doesn't give change), and for something more formal (possibly pedantic), we'd write "_takes only coins_".

Comment: @OscarBravo It doesn't really matter what I'm relying on, since the answerer simply comments on what a native speaker would say, nothing about why he would say it that way. I certainly don't care about formal grammar rules and say things as I like, which is a very native English speaker thing to do.

Comment: @Puppy Was your _comma-which_ example in your last sentence deliberate irony? I rather hope it was! :-)

Answer (score 4):

> Outside there is a money receiver which only accepts coins.

I think the app is right that "that" is marginally more realistic than "which" in this sentence... but the sentence has *much much* bigger issues, which it would be good to address! I would write:

> The vending machine outside doesn't take anything but coins.

First of all, "a money receiver" isn't a thing, at least not in America. I infer that we're talking about some kind of machine that accepts coins — maybe a parking meter, or a vending machine. But the phrase "money receiver" just makes me think of Polonius's advice in *Hamlet* — "neither a money giver nor a money receiver be," I think it was? ;)

Secondly (and the first thing *I* noticed, because I'm like this) is that the modifier "only" is misplaced in the original sentence. Obviously a money *receiver* would only *accept* coins! A machine that *produced* coins would be called something else.

I infer that the narrator was actually trying to say that "the machine accepts only *coins*"; that is, it doesn't accept *bills* (or "banknotes," to a Brit) or *credit cards* or whatever. It accepts only coins.

But in real life, if I'm telling someone about this machine, I wouldn't say that it "accepts only coins"; I would be *warning* the listener against some specific course of action that they might be about to try. For example, if I see them going outside with a dollar bill in hand, I might call out, "Hey, that machine doesn't take bills!" ("Really?" "Yeah, it only takes coins." Once we get down into the colloquial register, I admit that even I will naturally misplace the word "only," because to do otherwise sounds just as stilted and awkward as talking about "money receivers" or using the verb "accept" to mean "take as input.")

Finally, the formulation "There is a Y which *blahs*" strikes me as a bit of a Spanglish-ism. In English we'd generally just say "The Y *blahs*." Especially, we force the subject toward the beginning of the sentence. If I'm listing all the outdoor facilities at this location, sure: "*Outside* there's a vending machine, an ice chest, and a water hookup." But if I'm *giving you advice about the vending machine*, I would make it the subject of the sentence: "*The vending machine outside* is a little flaky."

Put all these minor flaws (and fixes) together, and you get:

> The vending machine outside doesn't take anything but coins.

Comment: Nitpick: A money receiver could theoretically accept bank notes instead of only coins. Also, ‘only accepts coins’ could mean that it is designed to take bank notes or coins, but currently does not properly handle bank notes (unlikely, but I have actually seen a vending machine before that was broken in exactly the opposite way, it was supposed to accept bank notes or coins, but wouldn’t properly accept coins).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn: What Brits call "banknotes," USians call "dollar bills." I _had_ mentioned "bills" in my answer, but I can see how that would have been confusing if you think of a "bill" only as the thing on a duck's face. :) Edited in a parenthetical which might help.

Comment: I had actually missed your reference, though FWIW I used the term ‘bank note’ here because even in parts of the US it’s a bit more generic than ‘bills’ (None of the Americans I know would call a 1000 JPY note a ‘bill’ for example).

Comment: I'd suggest moving the "only" to the very end - that also disambiguates the sentence: "The vending machine outside takes coins only.". But in this case that's not very necessary because the sane reader understand the implied warning (it doesn't take payment cards or bills etcetera). It's this sort of thing that makes natural language AI really hard.